# boolean values in Spring application.properties file?

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

Is it possible to have boolean values in Spring configuration file?

I wrote the following field in my bean:

```
@Value("${pdk.populatedemo}")
private boolean populateDemo;
```

but if causes the following exception:

```
Could not autowire field: private boolean com.inthemoon.pdk.data.DatabaseService.populateDemo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [boolean]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Invalid boolean value [1;]
```

here I tried

```
pdk.populatedemo=1;
```

in `application.properties`. I also tried `=true` and some others.

Comment: in `application.properties` I also tried `=true` *with semicolon at the end* ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The correct value for a boolean type would be

```
pdk.populatedemo=true
```

`1` is not a valid value for a boolean field and you must not use semicolons in your property file for a boolean value (as you clearly can see in the error message).

Comment: In springboot 2/spring 5 "pdk.populatedemo=true" is false and the mechanism was changed to a 1/0

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options:

```
# in case of set it hardcoded ALWAYS true
pdk.populatedemo=true

# in case of set it hardcoded ALWAYS false
pdk.populatedemo=false

# in case of set it dynamically,
# where isPopulatedemo is a system property or an environment variable having a string value either "true" or "false"
pdk.populatedemo=${isPopulatedemo}
```