# Spring @Value is not parsed correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have a dependency jar which has values configured in yaml as below:

```
app:
  settings:
    value1 : true
```

And the java code is

```
public class LoadConfig {

    @Value("${app.settings.value1}")
    private Boolean value1;
}
```

While deploying the spring boot app, in runtime, the dependency jar values are not parsed and below issue occurred.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'LoadConfig':
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'value1'; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException:**Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Boolean'**; nested 
    exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [**${app.settings.value1}**].
```

The issue is instead of value, path(app.settings.value1) is getting converted to Boolean and the error is thrown.

maven project structure is

```
MyJar --> app.jar
    |-> dependency.jar
```

Comment: can you format the yaml a little better

Comment: For non String values , you can try 

@Value("#{new Boolean('${app.settings.value1}")

Comment: @Value("#{new Boolean('${app.settings.value1:true}")

OR

@Value("'${app.settings.value1}")
private boolean value1 ;  //Note the use of primitive

Comment: the link which you have shared trying to convert 1 to boolean, where as in my case it is not reading the value and It is trying to convert whatever present inside @Value("") .

Comment: As a note, `@ConfigurationProperties` classes are almost always preferable to `@Value` in Boot.

Comment: This should work as posted in this question. I suspect something varies in your real code, and your edits did not preserve the difference.

Comment: does it matter the blankSpace behind the `value1`?

Comment: @user8814998 could you please show us the imports from the `LoadConfig` file?

Comment: Shouldn't `value1 : true` be `value1: true` in your YAML?

Comment: @xenteros, the imports are <br/> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

Answer (score 0):

Base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42735568/11733759) you can try:

```java
@Value("#{new Boolean('${app.settings.value1}')}")
private Boolean value1;
```

But the real problem is here:
`exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [**${app.settings.value1}**]`. It pass not the value but the label, that cannot be parsed as boolean.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code:

```
@Value("${app.settings.value1}")
private Boolean value1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Also it can be primitive:

```
@Value("${app.settings.value1:false}")
private boolean value1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following ways:

```
//If you need a Boolean object
@Value("#{new Boolean('${app.settings.value1}")
private Boolean value1;
```

OR

```
//If you need a primitive boolean
@Value("${app.settings.value1:true}")
private boolean value1;
```

Please check [boolean values in Spring application.properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529216/boolean-values-in-spring-application-properties-file)